# How to declare variables with plus/minus sign as subscript/superscript?

Tags: string-manipulation, variable-definitions, symbols, variable

I am pretty new to mathematica, so please forgive me if I ask any stupid questions.

I want to create a vector $a^{+}=[a^+_{k-2},a^+_{k-1},a^+_{k},a^+_{k+1},a^+_{k+2}]$ and then do some symbolic manipulation with it, but how do I use plus/minus sign as symbols rather than operators? Besides, when I type $a=[a_{k-2},a_{k-1},a_{k},a_{k+1},a_{k+2}]$, I get the error message 'Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of $a_{k-2}$'. Why and how to deal with this?

thanks

PS: I know I need to use curly bracket instead of square bracket when typing them in mathematica.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to avoid the recursion error; just don't use the same variable name for the lists and the elements of the list. To have the superscripts stay as symbols, can you just use strings? E.g. `alist = {a[k-2]^"+", a[k-1]^"+", ... }`

Comment: but even if I type $b=[a_{k-2},a_{k-1},a_{k}]$ I still get that recursion error.

Comment: Do `Clear[a,b]` first.

Comment: If you only want to do formatting, check out the function `SuperPlus` or `SuperDagger`.  Also, you get recursion error because there is an `a` on both the left and right sides of the `=` sign.  Opt for naming it `aVec` on left hand side.

Comment: You could also use a different symbol that looks similar to a plus sign, e.g., `FromCharacterCode[10010]`.

Comment: I think you should separate your desire to do computation from your desire to do pretty presentation. The plus symbol in your notation does not seem to have any purpose, so leave it out, do your calculations, and then add it in back at the end for presentation. Also, for your BESIDES question, never mix a variable  say $x$ with subscripted versions of $x$ (say $x_1, x_2$) in the same expression, unless you want problems. You could do xlis = {$x_1,x_2, $...}, but avoid $x =$ {$x_1,x_2,$ ...}